# Trouble getting QPrinter to link using cmake

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, qt5

So I've been trying to get my programs with QPrinter to work compile with cmake+mingw+qt5.2 but I'm having issues: the following test program doesn't compile because it cant find QPrinter which should be part of QtCore

```
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QApplication>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    QApplication a( argc, argv );

    return 0;
} // end
```

this is my cmake file

```
    SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER E:/Qt/Qt5.2.1/Tools/mingw48_32/bin/gcc.exe)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER E:/Qt/Qt5.2.1/Tools/mingw48_32/bin/g++.exe)
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

    PROJECT (test_prog)
    add_definitions(-std=c++11)
    SET( test_prog_SRCS test.cpp)
      # Tell CMake to run moc when necessary:
      set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
      # As moc files are generated in the binary dir, tell CMake
      # to always look for includes there:
      set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

      # Widgets finds its own dependencies.
      find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
      find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
      find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)

    include_directories(
        ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${Qt5Gui_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )

    add_executable(test_prog WIN32  ${test_prog_SRCS})
    target_link_libraries(test_prog ${Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES} ${Qt5Core_LIBRARIES} ${Qt5Gui_LIBRARIES} )
```

The Error is:

> test.cpp:1:20: fatal error: QPrinter: No such file or directory
>   `#include <QPrinter>`

Does anyone know the right incantations to get this to work?

Comment: Looks like missing `Qt5PrintSupport`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With CMake 2.8.11:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER E:/Qt/Qt5.2.1/Tools/mingw48_32/bin/gcc.exe)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER E:/Qt/Qt5.2.1/Tools/mingw48_32/bin/g++.exe)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

PROJECT (test_prog)
add_definitions(-std=c++11)
SET( test_prog_SRCS test.cpp)
# Tell CMake to run moc when necessary:
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
# As moc files are generated in the binary dir, tell CMake
# to always look for includes there:
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(Qt5PrintSupport REQUIRED)

add_executable(test_prog WIN32  ${test_prog_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(test_prog Qt5::PrintSupport)
```